# How to test for `Cannot iterate over null (null)` and print a user specifed string indicating the error?

Tags: json, jq

I got the following error when I try to access "a" when it does not exist. I don't want "?" as I want to print some custom string to indicate the error. Could you show me how to do it? Thanks.

```
$ jq '.a | .[]' <<< '{"a": [1, 2, 3] }'
1
2
3
$ jq '.a | .[]' <<< '{"b": [1, 2, 3] }'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over null (null)
$ jq '.a | .[]?' <<< '{"b": [1, 2, 3] }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if input has `a` as a field before expanding it

```
if has("a") then .a[] else "error message" end
```

Or use `try-catch`:

```
.a | try .[] catch "error message"
```

Note that `"error message"` is a normal JSON string in above programs, if you want to show a custom message instead of *Cannot iterate over null* but replicate the behavior of an error (like halting the program, returning a non-zero status etc), then you need something like:

```
.a | try .[] catch error("custom error message")
```